# Internal system error when opening Lotus Notes XPages database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, xpages

I have downloaded sample XPages database http://www.jmackey.net/groupwareinc/johnblog/johnblog.nsf/d6plinks/SurveyToolSample

and deployed it to server. I can open it without problem with my Lotus Notes 8.5.3, but my colleague cannot open it on his Lotus Notes 8.5.2 Standard Configuration.

He gets the following error:

```
**This Page Cannot Be Displayed**

Internal system error when processing the request for the page ( http://127.0.0.1/xsp/JHGNES!!Major %5CSurvey.nsf/HomePage.xsp?OpenXPage&xspRunningContext=Notes ). 
Please retry this request. 
Enforced by host JHGMELWEB01
If this condition persists, please contact your corporate network administrator and provide the code    shown below. 
Notification codes:     (1, INTERNAL_ERROR, http://127.0.0.1/xsp/JHGNES!!Major  %5CSurvey.nsf/HomePage.xsp?OpenXPage&xspRunningContext=Notes)
```

I have Recompiled all lotusScript in the database using my 8.5.3 client.

Any ideas what can be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Recompiling all Lotusscript does not re-compile XPages.
Try doing a clean of the project by opening the database in Domino Designer and then use Project - Clean in the menu. Clean removes all built code and then re-builds the code.

Answer (score 3):

In your 853 Designer, try recompiling the app to support 852 as the minimum release?
Launch the Application Properties in Designer, go to the XPages tab, then under 'Minimum Supported Release' select to compile this application to run on 'Release 8.5.2'.

For the vast majority of cases, apps built or compiles on current releases will work fine on previous releases without needing to do this step. Though in some cases, changes in the new release, like a new property for example, may cause failures in previous releases. This is what I'm guessing what is happening in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick responses. I have done more testing after I tried suggested solutions and it seems like the problem is not in the database itself but in this colleague's PC configuration, as it works on 5 other PCs running 8.5.2 and 8.5.2FP2.

Actually when you change "Minimum supported Release" on the xpages tab of app properties it prompts you to rebuild all the code.

The problem was in the location settings of that particular machine. After we removed contents of "Proxy configuration" it worked like a charm.